# What are the possible failure cases of React Native's AsyncStorage?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

React Native provides the [`AsyncStorage`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) library as a way to store persistent data in RN apps. In general, AsyncStorage is pretty straightforward to use, except for one aspect:

Both of the main `AsyncStorage` functions, `AsyncStorage.getItem` and `AsyncStorage.setItem` return `Promise`s. This is simple enough to understand: The actual querying or saving done by the function runs in the background, and the getting or saving of items might fail, requiring us to `catch` the error.

However, it seems that nowhere in the React Native documentation is it specified what, exactly, are the failure cases of `AsyncStorage` or which errors one should expect when calling `setItem`or `getItem`. Of course, one can deduce what might be a few of the error cases: One might try to `getItem` using an inexistent key, or one might try to `setItem` in a full or nearly full store, and the OS might refuse to release more disk space for your app, but it is frustrating not to have a full list.

It would be nice to know how exactly `AsyncStorage` might fail, so that people who are developing React Native apps which use data persistence might know exactly which failure cases they need to handle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code is open source, you can see when the calls fail, for example [here on android](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/storage/AsyncStorageModule.java) or [here for ios](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Modules/RCTAsyncLocalStorage.m).

The `getItem` call, fails, for example when requiring a nonexistent item. Other example may be `Failed to create storage directory.` which you can see in the ios module (for example when there's not enough space on device).

## Edit:

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/blob/LEGACY/docs/API.md#getitem) of `react-native-community/async-storage` ,`getItem` won't fail when requiring a nonexistent item, it will just return `null`.

Comment: It's still a pain to have to go through the source in order to see the list of failure cases, though. I'll wait a while before accepting to see if anyone knows whether this is properly documented.

Comment: Ah, so no one knows when it fails